# Accents using \capitalisewords

Tags: acronyms, accents, capitalization, acro, mfirstuc

I'm doing my acronyms with `acro` package. I capitalized the first letters using `\capitalisewords` from `mfirstuc` package. However, when the letter has an accent, the acronyms list doesn't look good, E. G.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\acsetup{list-long-format=\capitalisewords}
\DeclareAcronym{AW}{
short=AW,
long=\'{a} word\MakeLowercase{ with} \'{a}ccent
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms

This is an example of \ac{AW}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: See also [the UTF-8 section of the `mfirstuc` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.html#sec:utf8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\acsetup{list-long-format=\capitalisewords}
\DeclareAcronym{AW}{
short=AW,
long={\'{a}} word\space with {\'{a}}ccent
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms

This is an example of \ac{AW}
\end{document}
```

It gives the correct result on mine as far as I can understand (but I don't have your language installed).

Output:

[image]

May be if you could use XeLaTeX things would be easier but I don't really know because I never use such characters.

Comment: According to the manual of `mfirstuc` it should be `{\'{a}} word\space with {\'{a}}ccent`

Comment: @clemens I edited But I am not sure if this is the change you recommended. Feel free to edit.

Comment: The `\MakeLowercase` is not needed, I removed it

Comment: Thanks... I thought about that but was not sure. Thank you for the edit